# I'm doing login page using serverside validation, what should I fill in the place of the variable "prashanth" and "sharma"?

Tags: android, wordpress

I'm doing login page using server-side validation, what should I fill in the place of prashanth and sharma?

```
package web.com;


@WebServlet(name="AndroidResponse", urlPatterns={"/androidres.do"})
public class AndroidResponse extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String un,pw;
        un=request.getParameter("username");
        pw=request.getParameter("password");
        if(un.equalsIgnoreCase("prashant") && pw.equals("sharma"))
            out.print(1);
        else
            out.print(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about "divya" and "password"? Or maybe you want to tell us a little more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: for website i'm doing android app, so when ever the user clicks on username and password in the login page, the existence of that should be validated through website database. i followed this link:http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/login-application-for-android/......     in that link it has mentioned that above code has to be uploaded in the webserver

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this. 
The method `request.getParameter("username")` gives u a object, u have to downcast it string. hope this will work for you.

```
 String username = (String)request.getParameter("username");
 String password = (String)request.getParameter("password");
```